# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less

Tags: pandas

When I invoke a Pandas DataFrame `to_excel` method, the output file seems to be writing correctly, but I get this error message:

```
pandas\core\format.py:2190: RuntimeWarning: 
invalid value encountered in greater has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e6).any()
```

I refactored the code backwards (made it more clunky but still clear) and it works without error, and the file size is exactly the same and same # of records as the one that completed without error.

Comment: That's good to know.